# How to increase / scale Ant Design font theme without breaking styling

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am trying to increase the font on Ant Design 5, as it is far too small for most users to read. I tried to override the theme attributes, but as I do all of the antd component styling seems to break.

```
<ConfigProvider
    theme={{
      token: {
        fontSize: 18, 
        // controlHeight: 20, tried playing with this
        // lineHeight: 22, tried playing with this
        // size: 10, tried playing with this
      },
    }}
>
```

Docs: https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme

Playing with the theme-editor I wasn't able to get it to scale it up either: https://ant.design/theme-editor

The padding/margin doesn't seem to scale with the increased font. Does anyone know if there is an easier way to "scale" everything up while not making it look disastrous?

[image]
[image]

Comment: antd uses 14px as a default font size, when you change the font size it breaks because 18px is so big you, even 16 pixels is pretty good, and no there is no way to do this because antd components are styled to be on 14 pixels maybe you can change it to 16 is the max ... check out thier doc : https://ant.design/docs/spec/font